# Draggable true in rails map not work?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, gmaps4rails

I use gmaps4rails. I instance map in rails and it works but when i pass the atrribute draggable : true the map not work. This is my code .

```
handler = Gmaps.build('Google');
  handler.buildMap({ provider: {maxZoom: 5}, internal: {id: 'map'}}, function(){
  markers = handler.addMarkers([
        {
          "lat": 22,
          "lng": 22,
          "picture": {
            "width":  32,
            "height": 16
          },
          "infowindow": "hello!",
        },
        {
           "draggable": true
        }
      ]
      );
      handler.bounds.extendWith(markers);
      handler.fitMapToBounds();
      handler.map.centerOn({ lat: 22, lng: 22 })
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe if you move some of  this code to the controller (as per the Gmaps4Rails guide), you may have better luck. For example, try it like this:

```
def index
  @geolocations = [{:lat => 22, :lng => 22}]
  @hash = Gmaps4rails.build_markers(@geolocations) do |geolocation, marker|
    marker.lat geolocation[:lat]
    marker.lng geolocation[:lng]
    marker.infowindow ("hello!")
    marker.picture({"width" => 32, "height" => 16})
  end
end
```

And then for the JS:

```
var mapOptions = {};
var handler = Gmaps.build('Google');
handler.buildMap({ provider: {maxZoom: 5}, internal: {id: 'map'}}, function(){
    var markers = handler.addMarkers(<%= raw @hash.to_json %>, {draggable: true});
    handler.bounds.extendWith(markers);
    handler.map.centerOn([22, 22]);
    handler.fitMapToBounds();
});
```

For more on using the handler: https://github.com/apneadiving/Google-Maps-for-Rails/wiki/Js-Methods